# send form data to controller using backbone js

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, backbone.js

```
  var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults: {
                user_name: "",
                user_email: "",
                user_password: "",
            },

            initialize: function () {
                console.log('user has been intialized');
            },
            urlRoot: 'http://localhost/reddit/index.php/user_account/user'
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#submit").click(function(){
                var email = $("#uname").val();
                var password = $("#upass").val();

           if(email==''||password=='')
                {
                    alert("Please Fill All Fields");
                }
                else
                {
// AJAX Code To Submit Form.
                    var user = new User({user_email: email, user_password:password});
                    user.fetch({
                        success: function () {
                            var view1 = new SampleView({model: user, el: $("#logged_user")});
                            view1.render();
                        }
                    });
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
```

this is my code. i need to send user_name and user_password to controller in codeigniter. i checked values send from the view in controller. those were null.  can anyone help me ? Thanks

Comment: `.fetch` will make a GET request without sending any data. Try `user.save()` which will make a POST request or just make a custom jQuery `.ajax` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not share your controller code here.I think your controller must like this...try once

```
public function user($email,$password)
{

    echo $email."<br/>";
    echo $password;

    //perform operations

}
```

OR you can make jquery `ajax()` call like this...

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'http://localhost/reddit/index.php/user_account/user',
    data:{user_email: email, user_password:password},
    success:function()
    {
        var view1 = new SampleView({model: user, el: $("#logged_user")});
        view1.render();           
    }
});
```

And in Controller

```
public function user()
{

    $email = $this->input->post('user_email');
    $password = $this->input->post('user_password');

    //perform operations

}
```